# If I add more instances to my stack will they all get masked with the same Elastic IP or will they get new ones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

If I add more instances to my stack will they all get masked with the same Elastic IP or will they get new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) is attached to a single EC2 instance. You can detach and reattach it to another instance, but only one.